# test root-system password on IOS-XR

Tags: cisco

I've installed quite new NCS-5501-SE devices from Cisco. They're running well. I just remembered that then I initially deployed it, it asked me to set the root-system username and password, which is different from ones running in *XR VM* (router view).
I came to conclusion that I need to check if I remember that *root-system* user credentials correctly. Of course I can to enter the *#admin mode* from *XR VM* and change it. But for some reason, first I want to check if I remember them.
Maybe you guys know - is there any way to initiate a root-system user and password dialog to test the password from already running system ?

Thanks

Comment: *But for some reason, first I want to check if I remember them.*  And that reason is...?

Comment: thanks for being interested. The main reason - is i dont know if i remember it correctly. So if in a future there would be some device misbehavior for example crash of XR VM (Dont know if that is possible). I would not be able to log in to the system with root-system credentials and try to recover it. The only way for me would be to physicaly re-image the router. So trying to prevent this scenario. Yes, i can try to change it by entering sysadmin, but later - how to know if the change of credentials is in effect, etc ?